# Can Variable number of variables with incremental variableNames be created through reflection in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

Hi I have the following requirement.

I want to create variable number of String arrays in a method, based on the number of levels present.
For e.g

I have the variable numOfLevels (int) received from a jsp page.

Based on this I want to create:

```
String[] level1;
String[] level2;
String[] level3;
String[] level4;
```

etc ...

I know my requirement can be handled with Hashmaps and I've finally resorted to doing that, but I'm curious as to how this can be achieved with reflection in Java.

Many thanks in advance.

---

Hmm like a commenter pointed out, an almost similar question was asked at [Is there away to generate Variables' names dynamically in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192534/is-there-away-to-generate-variables-names-dynamically-in-java/1192561)

Thanks for the valuable inputs people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the same question as [is-there-away-to-generate-variables-names-dynamically-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192534/is-there-away-to-generate-variables-names-dynamically-in-java/1192561)

The winner was

> use the Java Scripting API

Answer (score 6):

Static languages cannot declare variables at runtime.

What you might want to use is an array of arrays

```
String[][] level = new String[numOfLevels][];

level[0] = ...
level[1] = ...
level[2] = ...
level[3] = ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Reflection can only show you what is, it can't change it (just like a mirror can only show what it reflects; changes to the mirror won't change the original object).

To change a class, you need to modify the bytecode. There are libraries for that ([cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/)) but it's not for the faint of heart. In your case, a map is the correct solution.