# Declare a variable with a variable?

Tags: java

I have the variable X, which is constantly changing. How would I be able to declare a new String named after the value of variable X?
I am using this in a while loop, where each cycle, I need to temporarily declare a variable to hold information.

Comment: how would other code reference this randomized name?  how about place each object into a Collection of some sort, like an array or map..

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: I should use a HashMap, but I would prefer to use variables here, is it possible though?

Comment: It is neither possible nor desirable, I think.

Comment: The only language I've ever used that had this ability was REXX.  (Boy, you could do some nasty and convoluted things with that feature!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible.  The compiler needs to know the names of all variable names at compile time, but your loop won't execute until runtime.  Use a HashMap as suggested by PoByBolek and Starfire1337.

Comment: It **is** possible, see the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192534/is-there-away-to-generate-variables-names-dynamically-in-java. Ths doesn't mean it's a good idea though :)