# How to make String value to call specific existed JButton variable name in java?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, string-conversion

So, I know there is this:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt("5");
String numtxt = Integer.toString(12);
double number = Double.parseDouble("4.5");
String numbertxt = Double.toString(8.2);
String letter = Character.toString('B');
char letter = "stringText".charAt(0);

so on...
```

but what I don't know how to make String value to call existed JButton variable name dynamically; is it even possible?

> Let's say, I have 4 JButton called btn1, btn2, btn3 and btnFillNumber;
>
> I create a String called buttonName;

```
package testing;

public class Testing extends javax.swing.JFrame {

String buttonName;
int num;

public Testing() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// Generated Code <<<-----

private void btnFillNumberActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    for(num = 1; num <= 3; num++){
        buttonName = "btn" + Integer.toString(num);
        JButton.parseJButton(buttonName).setText(num);
    }
}                                             

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    // Look and feel stteing code (optional) <<<-----

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Testing().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btn1;
private javax.swing.JButton btn2;
private javax.swing.JButton btn3;
private javax.swing.JButton btnFillNumber;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I know there's no JButton.parseJButton(), I just don't want to make complicated explaination, I simple want a convertion from String to call JButton's variable name dynamically.

See this:

```
    for(num = 1; num <= 3; num++){
        buttonName = "btn" + Integer.toString(num);
        JButton.parseJButton(buttonName).setText(num);
    }
```

I want to make a loop using a String with

- a fixed String value (btn) and
- increment number after it (1, 2, 3...) and
- make use to call a JButton.

I can just simply do this, but what if I got a 25 or more? So a loop what I wanted...

```
btn1.setText("1");
btn2.setText("2");
btn3.setText("3");
```

> Note that the value of these JButtons are not necessarily incremental in some purpose.

Output:

[image: Sample output]

My real development:

[image]

P.S. I use to make JFrame in NetBeans Design (just click and drag the objects in palette window like JPanel, JButton, etc., so I don't type the code manually except making my own logical Method; and I can't edit the code in grey background in Source View that was made automatically by Design View but in Design View itself. If you have tips and guide, I'll be happy to).

Comment: if i understand this right then one way could be to store the buttons in a `Map<String,JButton>`. Afterwards you could simply access them by `map.get("btn1")`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, maybe I gonna look about that.. still learning Java. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a Swing component by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958600/get-a-swing-component-by-name)

Comment: @Jan Jeremy my question is if each of JButtons has statics set of values or value for JButton can be changed at runtime, then this question can be anverable

Comment: @mKorbel what do you mean? You mean the value of btn1-btn3? (Can be change by setText).

No, they are not static, they can be assign to different value.

Comment: @Jan Jeremy if the concrete JButton has always the same properties,

Comment: @mKorbel yes, they have the same properties except the variable name. For now, the quantities of my JButton is fix in number, if I have 4 it's 4, if I have 3 it's 3. They are not dynamically made.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Map:

```
private Map<String,JButton> buttonMap = new HashMap<String,JButton>();
```

In your constructor add your buttons:

```
buttonMap.add("btn1", btn1);
buttonMap.add("btn2", btn2);
buttonMap.add("btn3", btn3);
buttonMap.add("btn4", btn4);
```

And in your action Listener / Loop whatever make:

```
String buttonName = "btn1"; //should be parameter or whatever
JButton button = buttonMap.get(buttonName);
```

As an alternative you could just as well set up an array of JButton:

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[4];

button[0] = new JButton(); //btn1
button[1] = new JButton(); //btn2
button[2] = new JButton(); //btn3
button[3] = new JButton(); //btn4
```

And access it

```
JButton but = button[Integer.parseInt(buttonString)-1];
```

Or by utilizing the possibility of adding custom properties to UI elements (you'll need a JComponent for that)

```
getContentPane().putClientProperty("btn1", btn1);
```

and later retrieving whith

```
JButton but = (JButton)getContentPane().getClientProperty("btn1");
```

Comment: (Hash)Map hasn't internal index better with util.List, then all additional params could be stored (depends of index) in [get/putClientProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10416286/714968) and/or by using Swing Action

Comment: with Map you can access items **by Name** - with List you access **by Index** only. The question was clearly worded for access **by Name** so a Map provides best result.

Comment: then reson for get/putClientProperty, is about siimplyfied all possible things without premature arrays (just my view, not flamewar)

Comment: You would use the get/putClientProperty on the **buttons**. And would still be able to do that if they're in a Map. Or do you suppose to **use the JPanel the buttons will be added to** as the "Map" to store the values?

Comment: yes, agree, exactly, it can be, but util.List is better array for, you have to hold index (can be required from everywhere) in (Hash)Map separatelly :-)

Comment: You mean instead of Array (which is poor choice) use a List? Yes, absolutely. That array example is just to show some alternatives.

Comment: :-) to your edit you have to multiply those paramaters with number,  numtxt, number,numbertxt, letter, char :-) thats reason for my  get/putClientProperty :-), to every JButtons, this is requirements by OP :-) phaaaa... :-)

Comment: This is not how I understood the question - let's wait for some feedback here.

Comment: result is then (get/putClientProperty) any type of array is useless

Comment: my helicopter view you can to see in my answer here

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Kevin's comment. The best concrete `Map<K,V>` class is probably `Hashtable<K,V>`. You don't even need to create the button name, just associate an integer with it if they are all numbered (and if `btnFillNumber` can be `0`).

```
Hashtable<Integer,JButton> buttonTable = new Hashtable<>();

// Fill buttonTable with buttons

JButton button = buttonTable.get(num);

if (button != null) {
    // Do something with button
}
```

Because of **autoboxing**, you don't need to create `Integer` objects to query the hashtable, `num` can be an `int` primitive.

Comment: (Hash)Map hasn't internal index better with util.List, then all additional params could be stored (depends of index) in [get/putClientProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10416286/714968) and/or by using Swing Action

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223125/replacement-for-obsolete-hashtable-class-in-java